# Unable to read certs from MMC after 3-5 minutes

Tags: java, ssl, https, java-11

I am using Amazon Coretto JDK 11 and am facing an issue with the SSL setup. I have configured Tomcat 9.x to read the SSL related trust store from the MMC. My application is able to service the Webservice request for about 3 minutes. After 3 minutes, all the Webservice requests fail with the below log:

```
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|24 89|https-openssl-apr-8443-exec-4|2024-02-01 10:10:26.775 EST|TransportContext.java:341|Fatal (CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (
"throwable" : {
  sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
  Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
    ... 154 more}
```

It seems like the JDK is not able to read the certificates after a couple of minutes. So, we tried to enable extra logging using the following Java args (the first one is to point to the MMC).

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=Windows-ROOT
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose:keymanager:trustmanager
-Djava.security.debug=certpath
```

After enabling the debug level logging, we were able to see that the certificates were loaded twice. 360 certificates were loaded the first time. But only 150 certificates were loaded the second time, and we are observing this issue right after the certificates are loaded for the second time. We could get the count of the certs from the below log which prints all the certificates that are being loaded.

```
X509TrustManagerImpl.java:79|adding as trusted certificates (
  "certificate" : { ..... }
```

We had identified that adding the certificate in cacerts resolved this issue but couldn't understand why the certificates would be loaded from cacerts when we are pointing to Windows-ROOT (MMC).

Could anyone please help me understand why and where the certificates are being loaded from the second time. If the certs are loaded from cacerts, why are the certs loaded from cacerts.